# Linux - How to track all files accessed by a process?

Tags: linux, file, trace

Is there a way to track all file I/O for a given process? All I really need is the locations of files being read from/written to from a given process (and ideally if it was a read or write operation although that's not as important).

I can run the process and track it rather than needing to attach to an existing process which I would assume is significantly simpler. Is there any kind of wrapper utility I can run a process though that will monitor file access?

Comment: [Continuously monitor files opened/accessed by a process](https://superuser.com/q/348738/241386)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

### `lsof`:

Try doing this as a starter :

```
lsof -p <PID>
```

this command will list all currently open files, fd, sockets for the process with the passed process ID.

For your special needs, see what I can offer as a solution to monitor a php script :

```
php foo.php & _pid=$!
lsof -r1 -p $_pid
kill %1 # if you want to kill php script
```

### `strace`:

I recommend the use of `strace`. Unlike `lsof`, it stays running for as long as the process is running. It will print out which syscalls are being called when they are called. `-e trace=file` filters only for syscalls that access the filesystem:

```
sudo strace -f -t -e trace=file php foo.php
```

or for an already running process :

```
sudo strace -f -t -e trace=file -p <PID>
```

Comment: Thanks that's a good starting point! It works for processes already running at the moment it's run. I'm trying to do this for a PHP script for its entire execution, tracking the files from the start of the process until it exists. Looking at the help, There's a -r repeat option but this seems to periodically scan the files that are open by the process rather than have been opened.

Essentially I want to do this:

   lsof -p $$ && exec php foo.php

This doesn't seem to list files that are opened by foo.php

Comment: thanks, that's certainly providing more relevant information and showing all the php extensions being loaded, the script contains <?php echo fopen('file.txt', 'r'); ?>  unfortunately, file.txt is not listed in the output. I can verify the file is being opened by amending the script to print the contents of file.txt but I still don't see file.txt in the output of lsof.

Comment: To properly trace an AppImage, I needed to run `strace` as root but the command using my own user. This got the job done: `sudo strace -fte trace=%file -u $(id -un) <COMMAND>`

Comment: Mixing your two solutions together becomes perfect: `php foo.php & sudo strace -f -t -e trace=file -p $!` especially for short running tasks.

Answer (score 8):

Besides strace there is another option which does not substantially slow down the monitored process. Using the Liunx kernel's [fanotify](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fanotify.7.html) (not to be confused with the more popular inotify) it is possible to monitor whole mount-points for IO-activity. With [unshared mountnamespaces](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/mount_namespaces.7.html) the mounts of a given process can be isolated fromt the rest of the system (a key technology behind docker).

An implementation of this concept can be found in [shournal](https://github.com/tycho-kirchner/shournal), which I am the author of.

Example on the shell:

```
$ shournal -e sh -c 'cat foo > bar'
$ shournal --query --history 1
...
  1 written file(s):
     /home/user/bar
  1 read file(s):
     /home/user/foo
```

Comment: External links are always highly appreciated as sources, but imagine this one was to become invalid - your solution would be unsalvageable for future SO users. Please consider posting code here and explaining your solution so we all can learn.

Comment: @harmonica141: That's always the problem: what to write and what to omit...
A complete, minimal example would be not much shorter than the example at the bottom at http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fanotify.7.html . In fact, it could be almost the same with a leading 
`unshare( CLONE_NEWNS);`. Do you think it would be helpful to include the full source here?

Answer (score 2):

strace is an amazing tool but its output is a bit verbose.
If you want you can use a tool I've written which processes strace output and provide a CSV report of all files accessed (TCP sockets too) with the following data:
1. Filename
2. Read/Written bytes
3. Number of read/write operations
4. Number of time the file was opened

It can be run on new processes or processes already running (using /proc/fd data).
I found it useful for debugging scenarios and performance analysis.
You can find it here: [iotrace](https://github.com/avner-levy/iotrace)

Example output:

```
Filename, Read bytes, Written bytes, Opened, Read op, Write op
/dev/pts/1,1,526512,0,1,8904
socket_127.0.0.1:47948->127.0.0.1:22,1781764,396,0,8905,11
myfile.txt,65,0,9,10,0
pipe:[3339],0,0,0,1,0
```

Afterward, you can process the CSV data in Excel or other tools for sorting or other analysis required.
The downside is you need to download & compile and it isn't always 100% accurate.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this may lessen the performance impact of the file activity monitoring.

```
$ watch -n 2.0 timeout 0.2 strace -p `pgrep myprogram` -fe trace=file
```

Where `myprogram` is the process name, `2.0` is the idle period between each monitoring period and `0.2` is the length of the monitoring period in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a big fan of [fatrace](https://github.com/martinpitt/fatrace/).

Example:

```
$ sudo fatrace -p $PID
```